# How do we call this kind of bread

Tags: word-request, vocabulary, food

I've checked different bread names: breadsticks, flatbread, oats, pita.. but none of them seems to fit.

[image]

These are usually very healthy - fat-free / lowfat, related to different diet recommendations.

Answer (score 2):

They are not common in the US, but we would most likely call them breakfast biscuits (or possibly breakfast cookies). [Here is an example.](http://www.belvitabreakfast.com) You might also want to look up breakfast bars,  energy bars, or granola bars.

Comment: I'm not sure belVita "breakfast biscuits" are a great example of US usage, [since they were originally launched outside the US...](http://www.just-food.com/news/kraft-to-launch-belvita-biscuits-in-the-us_id117760.aspx)

Comment: They are the only ones I've seen in grocery stores. Granted, I'm not looking for this item in particular.